# Firefox+GNOME workspaces Open a New Window

Tags: gnome, 20.04, firefox, workspaces

I have 4 fixed Workspaces (set by Tweaks).

FireFox is running in workspace 1 (by default, set by Tweaks - Startup Applications).

If in (say) workspace 3 and I right click Firefox Web Browser icon in the dock and select `Open a New Window`, it will open the new window in workspace 1 overlaying the already open FF in that workspace.

Is there a discrete setting I have missed which allows the new window to open in the workspace from which it was selected?