# Open link in the already open browser instead of default

Tags: browser, default-browser

My default browser is Firefox. However, if Google Chrome is open and I click any link outside that browser (in a PDF or Telegram, for example), the default behavior is to open Firefox to access the link I've just clicked.

Is it possible to open a new browser only if no one is already open, using the already open browser instead of the default when available?

Comment: related (unanswered) question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1307357/firefoxgnome-workspaces-open-a-new-window

Comment: I don't think it's related… The linked question is about opening the browser directly, while I want to open _links_ with the open browser, instead of the default one.

Comment: Same meat, different gravy. They are closely related enough to link. I was not using the link to answer your question nor was I denigrating your question but merely supporting it.

Comment: If such a solution existed, then imagine you have two different browsers currently open. In what browser should the link be opened?

Comment: @raj in case Firefox is already open (and the default browser), I think it should have priority...

Answer (score 0):

If you click on any link, it will open in the new tab of the default browser. There is no other solution. You can only copy the link, and  paste in the desired browser tab.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help!

Answer (score -1):

Most likely this is not an solutions for your problem, but in my case I had to configure Firefox to be the default browser. Since on my Ubuntu Chrome was the default, any links opened in it, though Firefox was opened as well. Once I have changed the default to Firefox, it worked out.